# Python: multiple indexes received by recv() function

Tags: python-3.x

The following is my client side code in python where recv function receive names of online users which are updated in a list whenever a user connects in server code and send one online user (one index of array) at a time. but the problem is that recv function recv multiple indexes of list not one at a time?

```
buff_size=1024
while(1):
   user=client.recv(buff_size)
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What do you mean by "recv function recv multiple indexes of list not one at a time?" It should receive whatever you send from the server side.

Comment: From server side i send one index of list at a time using loop but client receives 2 indexes like i send 'arslan' then 'haider' and try to print separately but it prints ArslanHaider not Arslan first then haider

Comment: Can you add the code for server side?

Comment: def Threaded_Function(c,):
    
    name = c.recv(1024)
    names.append(name)
    clients.update({name:c})
    for i in range(len(names)-1):
        c.send(names[i])
  
    for i in range(len(names)-1):
        clients[names[i]].send(name)

Comment: Its difficult to guess the indentation without proper formatting.